# How do I prevent the change in orientation when rotating using RotateTransform?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this Image control with a TransformGroup:

```
<Image x:Name="mainImageCtrl" 
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" 
       Source="{Binding Image}">

     <Image.RenderTransform>
          <TransformGroup>
               <TranslateTransform/>
               <RotateTransform />
          </TransformGroup>
     </Image.RenderTransform>

</Image>
```

With a click of a button, the Image will rotate either 90 degrees left or right. I used DoubleAnimation:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].Angle" 
                 By="90" 
                 Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

With a click of another button, the Image will then move either left, right, up or down:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].X" 
                 By="200" 
                 Duration="0:0:1"/>

<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].Y" 
                 By="200" 
                 Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

The problem is say, when I rotate the image 90 degrees right the X and Y orientation changes. So when I attempt to move the image left, the image seems to move up because of the change in orientation.

How do you prevent the change in orientation when an element is rotated? If it's not possible, how can I have a decent workaround on this?

Comment: Why not just reverse the order of the transformations in the TransformGroup? First RotateTransform, then TranslateTransform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the image in a container, a 1x1 Grid for instance, and move that container instead of moving the image itself. The container will not know about the rotation and should move as intended.

Comment: SWEET. this never even crossed my mind. Thank you for your suggestion.